# PHP Loading MySQL Columns For a UniqieID Then Updating Columns

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry very new to PHP and MySQL. I'm pretty close to having what I need. I created a database that hold values as shown here:

[image: SQL Table / Values]

I was able to find some things online to create a form and initially get the data into the database

[image: Customer Creation Form]

What I would like to do is have another page to load values for a specific customer by searching for their uniqueid. So have a input box where you input the uniqueid then the current values for that customer get loaded into a form just like the "Customer Creation Form". Then be able to update the loaded values in the the form and save it back. The enddate is probably the field that would be updated the most.

Comment: Have a look at PHP's session array. Once you insert using a query, you get the last inserted id and set this as a session variable. Then on the edit form page you would query to select the data from the database using the ID stored in the session array. This is just one way to handle this.

Comment: It's pretty likely this could be edited a year after initial creation.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure here. Are you having users login? You will then need some way to determine who the customer is a year out. Typically this is with a login account. Then the session can setup the ID upon successful login. Then you can use this ID to select the record from the database. Regardless, somehow you need to get the record's id for select.

Comment: No customers will login. It will be an admin on our side that updates the enddate if the customer renews a product. So basically all i'm looking to do if have the ability to input the uniqueid (We can get that from a report already) load the enddate value into a date form allow us to change it and write it back to the uniqueid for that customer in mysql

Comment: Even just a form with an input for the ID and a date could work if we could just set a new date value and use a where clause with the value in the ID input

Comment: One other option is to list all the records on a page. Then create a link to the update page with a query variable contaning the ID. So, for example, <a href="update.php?id=THE_ID">Edit</a>. Then on update.php you would grab the ID from the query string using $_GET['id'], and insert into the select query to get the record. I won't go into validation/filtering here, but you want to check that $_GET['id'] is indeed a valid ID.

Comment: Let me see what  I can figure out. This is my first time playing with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax requests and PHP to update the form live (or update once the user has entered the UniqueId)
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

To return multiple values grabbed from the database, use php to create an array return it as a json file.

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: Not sure the rules here on this, but do you do side projects for $? Is this something you think you could help out with?

Comment: I can help side projects for free actually depending on the workload :)

Comment: interesting I would be happy and want to give you something. Anyway to reach out to you better than on here?

Comment: Erm, what platform would you prefer? also i have a semi-working prototype for this which im still currently developing now

Comment: got you msg on FB and replied. You may need to accept it.